# Swift storyboard cross dissolve transition flashes different view controller

Tags: swift, storyboard, viewcontroller, presentviewcontroller, dispatch-queue

I am creating an app with cross dissolve transitions. The issue occurs when a view controller is presented and a previous screen flashes for a split second every time a cross dissolve transition happens until the app is forced closed and restarted. A lot of the view controllers are displayed in 4 different ways using the code listed below. Some are changed using a button from one view controller linked to another view controller with using storyboard's "show" or "show detail" which is not included in the code below. Thanks for any help in advance!

Code:

METHOD 1

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

METHOD 2

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let alert = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Alerts")
        alert.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
        alert.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: I'd say there's nothing wrong with snippets you have in the question, so the problem is somewhere else. Could you provide the question with a minimal reproducible example?